# Get data monthly from Landsat 8 image-collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

I am doing classification with Landsat 8 and other information to predict farm land use. I want to use monthly data(Monthly composite) rather than data from 2015-01-01' to '2016-12-22'. I think I should use ImageCollection.toArray() but i am not sure how to use it.

```
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var snowBitMask = (1 << 4);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);

  // Get the pixel QA band.
var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0);
return image.updateMask(mask);
}



var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2016-12-22')
    .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',20)) // filter on Cloud Cover
    .map(maskL8sr) 
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .median())  
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min:0, max: 3000}, 'ture  colour image');
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of research on this forum (and the Google Earth Engine discussion forum) will get you further:

[Getting weekly mean composite in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315354/getting-weekly-mean-composite-in-google-earth-engine)

[reduce image collection to get annual monthly sum precipitation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258344/reduce-image-collection-to-get-annual-monthly-sum-precipitation/258379)